# How to debug a Deno Typescript code on Windows 10, x64

Tags: deno

I 'm trying to debug a Deno project, but I dont know, how to debug this on Windows 10 using the **lldb debugger** as the documentation says.

The LLDB, on windows 10 seems to be not so easy to install.

```
///reference path="../../deno.d.ts"
import * as deno from 'deno';
import { color } from 'https://deno.land/x/colors/main.ts';

const s = new Set();
[*] s.add('test')

console.log(s);
```

> [*] <-- a breakpoint

Answer (score 2):

In order to debug with Deno:

1. Add somewhere in your code a `debugger;` line of code.
2. Run with `--inspect-brk` flag. `deno run --inspect-brk ...` or deno `test --inspect-brk ...` to debug tests.
3. Open `chrome://inspect` page on Chrome.
4. On the Remote Target section press to "inspect".
5. Press the Resume script execution button, the code will pause just in your breakpoint.

Reference: https://aralroca.com/blog/learn-deno-chat-app#debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you use VSCode here is a `launch.json` I am using.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Deno",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "-A", "--inspect-brk", "index.ts"],
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```